# Extracting text between two delimiters in a file and writing to a given filename

Tags: linux, shell, awk, sed, grep

I'd like to be able to extract snippets from my code for documentation purposes.  I can do this everytime I compile the code cheaply and it's an easy way to keep the code and documentation (at least snippets) up to date.

So I'd like take a file `source.cc` with something like this in it:

```
// DOCSNIP: source_def.snip
[code]
// DOCSNIP
```

There may be more than one of these in a file obviously.  The gist is I'd like to delimit a region of code (I'm not married to the syntax), along with a filename to stick it in, and write the content between the delimiters ("[code]" in this case) to a file (source_def.snip).

What would be the easiest way with standard tools (awk/sed/grep) to extract these blocks to their respective files?

Comment: Please add your desired output for that sample input to your question.

Comment: Already there but updated.

Comment: `awk '/DOCSNIP/,/DOCKSNIP/' code.file | head -n -1 > new.txt ; s=$(grep -oP "(?<=DOCSNIP:\s)(.*)" new.txt) ; cat new.txt | tail -n -1 > "$s"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk '/\/\/ DOCSNIP:/{f=$NF} f{print > f} /\/\/ DOCSNIP$/{f=""}' file

$ head sou*

// DOCSNIP: source_def.snip
[code]
// DOCSNIP
```

not going to work if you have spaces in filenames.

If you don't want the delimiter lines, just reorder the statements

```
$ awk '/\/\/ DOCSNIP$/{f=""} f{print > f} /\/\/ DOCSNIP:/{f=$NF}' file
```

will only print what's in between.

Comment: Idk why you're being downvoted, can we exclude the delimiters from the output?  Otherwise this is exactly what I need.

Comment: This will work until if/when you get to about 20 output files and then it'll start failing with "too many open files" errors unless you're using GNU awk. You should add a `close(f)` before either of the `f=...` assignments for it to work in all awks regardless of the number of output files.

Answer (score 0):

Using AWK

```
awk '/\/\/ DOCSNIP:/{f=1;print $3;next} /\/\/ DOCSNIP/{f=0} f'
source_def.snip
[code]
```

This prints from first DOCSNIP to second DOCSNIP and also output the filename

Comment: Close, I'd like to actually extract the file name (source_def.snip) and write to that file, possibly in another directory.

Answer (score 0):

I like perl because there aren't different flavors of it.  That said, I think I prefer awk for this one.  Still, the perl version (same basic idea as the accepted answer):

```
perl -ne 'BEGIN{my $fh} {close $fh if /\/\/ DOCSNIP[^:]/; print { $fh } "$_" if $fh!=0; open ($fh, ">>", "$1") or die if /\/\/ DOCSNIP:\s*(.+?)$/; }' main.cc
```

This supports spaces in the filenames, which I don't imagine is a feature you need :)

And a prep that deletes the snip files that and gives you expected output:

```
 perl -ne 'print if /\/\/ DOCSNIP:/../\/\/ DOCSNIP[^:]/; unlink "$1" if /\/\/ DOCSNIP:\s*(.+?)$/' main.cc
```